# Rails - Including associations with dynamic conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Given a school model and a student model with the school having a has_many relation to student:

```
has_many :students, :conditions => proc  { "year_id=#{send(:active_year_id)}" }
```

where active_year_id is a method defined in the school model, I'm encountering an error that "active_year_id is undefined" when calling:

```
School.where(:active => true).includes(:students)
```

The condition works fine when I do, say,

```
School.where(:id => 10).students
```

Only when I try to use includes do I get that error. Is that the right behavior. If not, what am I doing wrong and how do I fix ?

Using Rails 3.0.9, REE 1.8.7.

Comment: would be great to hear if you found any solution other than just ditching the include.

Comment: I'm having the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502307/rails-includes-doesnt-work-when-there-is-a-proc-in-the-association-condition

Comment: @VijayDev in my replicated example the code `School.where(:id => 10).students` raise another exception which is `undefined method `students' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fcc4b192368>` because the return value of `where` is a relation object. Are you sure that your code works and it's not `School.find(10).students` (which works as expected)

Answer (score 10):

This is a bit old, but I see the question a lot and have not seen any satisfactory solutions. Adding a condition like this is essentially equivalent to creating an association with two public/private keys.

@Fabio is right in saying "*the context in where the proc is executed is different depending of how it's called.*"  However I think you can overcome the "active_year_id is undefined" problem.

In the example:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students, :conditions => proc  { "year_id=#{send(:active_year_id)}" }
  ...
```

the issue is that in some situations, the proc is executed in the context of a particular School object and sometimes as an ActiveRecord::Associations::JoinDependency::JoinAssociation.  I solved this using a slightly more complicated proc, like this:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students, :conditions => proc  { 
      self.respond_to?(:active_year_id) ?
        {year_id: self.active_year_id} : 
        'students.year_id = schools.active_year_id'
    }
```

So, when the condition is calculated for an actual school object, **self** responds to the active_year_id attribute accessor and you can provide a hash as the condition (which works more nicely than just an interpolated string for creating associated objects, etc.)

When the context does not present **self** as an actual school object, (which, as you noted, occurs when called using an **include** clause, for example,) the context is a JoinAssociation and the string form of the condition works just fine using field names rather than values.

We found this solution let us use the dynamic association successfully.

Comment: As per the original question, this solution works for Rails 3.  It looks like Rails 4 will have some new association options (or at least some new method signatures.)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is not possible to achieve because the context in where the proc is executed is different depending of how it's called. I've made a basic app with your models and this is what happens when you call the various methods ([ap is this](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print)):

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students, :conditions => proc { ap self; "year_id=#{send(:active_year_id)}" }  
end
```

When you call the students relation from a school instance the context of the proc is the given `School` instance so it does respond to the `active_year_id` method

```
[31] pry(main)> School.first.students
  School Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schools".* FROM "schools" LIMIT 1
#<School:0x007fcc492a7e58> {
                :id => 1,
              :name => "My school",
    :active_year_id => 1,
           :year_id => 1,
        :created_at => Tue, 08 May 2012 20:15:19 UTC +00:00,
        :updated_at => Tue, 08 May 2012 20:15:19 UTC +00:00
}
  Student Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."school_id" = 1 AND (year_id=1)
+----+----------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | name           | school_id | year_id | created_at              | updated_at              |
+----+----------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | My student     | 1         | 1       | 2012-05-08 20:16:21 UTC | 2012-05-08 20:16:21 UTC |
| 2  | Second student | 1         | 1       | 2012-05-08 20:18:35 UTC | 2012-05-08 20:18:35 UTC |
+----+----------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
2 rows in set
```

But when you call the includes relation the context is different and what the proc receive as self is `Student` class, so it doesn't respond to that method and this will trigger the error

```
[32] pry(main)> School.includes(:students).all
  School Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schools".* FROM "schools" 
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base {
            :id => :integer,
          :name => :string,
     :school_id => :integer,
       :year_id => :integer,
    :created_at => :datetime,
    :updated_at => :datetime
}
NoMethodError: undefined method `active_year_id' for #<Class:0x007fcc4a6a3420>
from /Users/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'
```

I think that a has_many relation can't be used with that kind of proc which relies on an instance method of a School instance. I think that the only way to use procs as [described here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-conditions) is to compute some condition at runtime which doesn't involve instance methods (time conditions, where with data from unrelated models and so on).

Moreover the `School.includes(:students).all` in my example cannot work because it should call  the `active_year_id` method on **every** instance of `School` (which should be retrieved from db before the includes could be evaluated) and thus vanishing the effect of the `includes` intended behavior.

All of this is valid if the `active_year_id` is a computed method defined in `School` class based on instance data. Instead if the `active_year_id` is not a method but a field (a db column) of the `School` class you can play with [joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) and [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to achieve a result similar to what you want to achieve but it should be coded by hand.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but there is not a enough room.

So:

```
School.where(:id => 10).students
```

And:

```
School.where(:active => true).includes(:students)
```

Are two totally different things.

The first is the same thing as `School.find(10).students` where it returns the found schools students.

The Second `School.where(:active => true).includes(:students)` is quite different. You are finding schools with the value `active == true` and including `students` but that does nothing with the students. It only returns the schools.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think the implied answer from @Codeglot may be that you need to tag on a `.students` to your `School.where(:active => true).includes(:students)` query.

Comment: @codeglot: I understand they are two different things. I am saying that the error happens only when using includes. When I do the query with includes, Rails does another query for students, right. In that query, I need the condition in the proc to be appended.

Answer (score 0):

FYI you can access the current collection the include is called on ... this might help in some cases:

```
belongs_to :ticket, -> (t) { where(account_id: (t || self.first).account_id) }
```