# Rails' includes() doesn't work with dynamic association conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

Working on a multi-tenant app where most of my models will have a tenant_id field so I can ensure read permissions by finding through the association (`current_tenant.applications.find(params[:id])`):

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tenant
  has_many :app_questions, :conditions => proc {{:tenant_id => tenant_id}}, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

I like how this allows me to elegantly create a new AppQuestion with the tenant_id set automatically:

```
@application = current_tenant.applications.find(params[:app_question][:application_id])
@question = @application.app_questions.build(params[:app_question])
#...
```

Problem is, when I try to use `includes()` to eager-load the association it throws an error:

```
current_tenant.applications.where(:id => params[:id]).includes(:app_questions => :app_choices).first

NoMethodError (undefined method `tenant_id' for #<Class:0x007fbffd4a9420>):
  app/models/application.rb:7:in `block in <class:Application>'
```

I could refactor so that I don't have to have the proc in the association conditions, but am wondering if anyone has a better solution.

The ref [does say](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-conditions): "If you need to evaluate conditions dynamically at runtime, use a proc"

Comment: just found another poster with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684521/rails-including-associations-with-dynamic-conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've replied to the other question with more details trying to explain why this cannot work.

When they say dynamic is because the proc can be executed at runtime, but **not** in the context of an existing instance of the `Application` class because it doesn't exist when you invoke this relation

```
Application.where(:id => params[:id]).includes(:app_questions => :app_choices)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ability for `:conditions` to accept a `proc` isn't documented in the ref.  I suspect it doesn't work the way you guessed it might.

`:conditions` accepts either an SQL `WHERE` clause, or a hash that can be turned into on.  It's inserted into the SQL that gets the :app_questions  records, and if it's a `proc` it's only called once to get the snippet for the SQL statement to be constructed.

It might help to have a look at your database relationships.  Should app_questions link to tenants or applications?

Comment: Actually, it is: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-conditions QUOTE: "If you need to evaluate conditions dynamically at runtime, use a proc:"

Comment: And as mentioned, most of my models have a tenant_id on them. It's redundant, but it optimizes permissions checking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the relation itself works you could try `preload`  instead of `includes`